# How to determine if npm actually upgraded a module

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am writing a script a part of which should upgrade a module and return if was upgraded report it back.
tried running `npm install -g <module> --loglevel verbose`
but running it back to back twice doesn't yield any useful log info to know if anything was being done. please point out if I missed something.

*I understand that `npm info <module> version` can be used to check for the module's version but I find it silly that I cannot determine if `npm install module` actually did anything.

console logs:

Running after fresh install:
`npm install -g npm --loglevel verbose`

```
npm verb cli [
    npm verb cli   'C:\\ProgramData\\nvm\\v16.13.2\\node.exe',
    npm verb cli   'C:\\ProgramData\\nvm\\v16.13.2\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
    npm verb cli   'install',
    npm verb cli   '-g',
    npm verb cli   'npm',
    npm verb cli   '--loglevel',
    npm verb cli   'verbose'
    npm verb cli ]
    npm info using npm@8.1.2
    npm info using node@v16.13.2
    npm timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
    npm timing config:load:defaults Completed in 3ms
    npm timing config:load:file:C:\ProgramData\nvm\v16.13.2\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 3ms
    npm timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
    npm timing config:load:cli Completed in 5ms
    npm timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
    npm timing config:load:file:C:\ProgramData\nvm\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
    npm timing config:load:project Completed in 3ms
    npm timing config:load:file:C:\Users\devic\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
    npm timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
    npm timing config:load:file:C:\ProgramData\nvm\v16.13.2\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
    npm timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
    npm timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
    npm timing config:load:credentials Completed in 2ms
    npm timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 2ms
    npm timing config:load Completed in 21ms
    npm timing npm:load:configload Completed in 21ms
    npm timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
    npm timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 1ms
    npm timing config:load:flatten Completed in 7ms
    npm timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 5ms
    npm timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
    npm timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 1ms
    npm timing npm:load Completed in 98ms
    npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
    npm timing idealTree:init Completed in 8ms
    npm timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 3ms
    npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm 22ms (cache hit)
    npm timing idealTree:#root Completed in 69ms
    npm timing idealTree:node_modules/npm Completed in 1ms
    npm timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 75ms
    npm timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 1ms
    npm timing idealTree Completed in 95ms
    npm timing reify:loadTrees Completed in 612ms
    npm timing reify:diffTrees Completed in 7ms
    npm timing reify:retireShallow Completed in 17ms
    npm timing reify:createSparse Completed in 1ms
    npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/npm Completed in 9452ms
    npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
    npm timing reify:diffTrees Completed in 10ms
    npm timing reify:loadBundles Completed in 11124ms
    npm timing reify:unpack Completed in 10ms
    npm timing reify:unretire Completed in 44ms
    npm timing build:queue Completed in 17ms
    npm timing build:link:node_modules/npm/node_modules/opener Completed in 44msnpm timing build:link:node_modules/npm Completed in 80ms
    npm timing build:link:node_modules/npm/node_modules/qrcode-terminal Completed in 127ms
    npm timing build:link Completed in 133ms
    npm timing build:deps Completed in 157ms
    npm timing build Completed in 159ms
    npm timing reify:build Completed in 161ms
    npm http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 721ms
    npm timing auditReport:getReport Completed in 728ms
    npm timing metavuln:cache:get:security-advisory:ansi-regex:gipfqiXURkkimm8+IyoEer5YC1ntqyorXe7xXSHfbxT4Q2N0cl4sjpCXLBfNQSZpCf2C6BCCpq61JXzBTOWL+g== Completed in 78ms
    npm timing reify:trash Completed in 539ms
    npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-regex 93ms (cache hit)
    npm timing metavuln:packument:ansi-regex Completed in 96ms
    npm timing metavuln:load:security-advisory:ansi-regex:1004946 Completed in 1ms
    npm timing metavuln:calculate:security-advisory:ansi-regex:1004946 Completed in 100ms
    npm timing metavuln:cache:get:security-advisory:strip-ansi:VNH7BZLDPXeb+XyBHjziFezTzkb3wUEeYZF30Shwpq+9ErFf3ja9WpDN5+1N0ZmzJRrF78Jsd1Rv6URhv1/2cQ== Completed in 4ms
    npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi 12ms (cache hit)
    npm timing metavuln:packument:strip-ansi Completed in 15ms
    npm timing metavuln:load:security-advisory:strip-ansi:gipfqiXURkkimm8+IyoEer5YC1ntqyorXe7xXSHfbxT4Q2N0cl4sjpCXLBfNQSZpCf2C6BCCpq61JXzBTOWL+g== Completed in 0ms
    npm timing metavuln:calculate:security-advisory:strip-ansi:gipfqiXURkkimm8+IyoEer5YC1ntqyorXe7xXSHfbxT4Q2N0cl4sjpCXLBfNQSZpCf2C6BCCpq61JXzBTOWL+g== Completed in 18ms
    npm timing auditReport:init Completed in 121ms
    npm timing reify:audit Completed in 854ms
    npm timing reify Completed in 12630ms
```

Running again:
`npm install -g npm --loglevel verbose`

```
npm verb cli [
npm verb cli   'C:\\ProgramData\\nvm\\v16.13.2\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\ProgramData\\nvm\\v16.13.2\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '-g',
npm verb cli   'npm',
npm verb cli   '--loglevel',
npm verb cli   'verbose'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@8.3.2
npm info using node@v16.13.2
npm timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:defaults Completed in 3ms
npm timing config:load:file:C:\ProgramData\nvm\v16.13.2\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms
npm timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
npm timing config:load:cli Completed in 5ms
npm timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:project Completed in 2ms
npm timing config:load:file:C:\Users\devic\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:file:C:\ProgramData\nvm\v16.13.2\etc\npmrc Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 2ms
npm timing config:load Completed in 22ms
npm timing npm:load:configload Completed in 22ms
npm timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:flatten Completed in 7ms
npm timing npm:load:display Completed in 49ms
npm verb logfile C:\Users\devic\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-21T03_21_17_105Z-debug-0.log
npm timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 18ms
npm timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load Completed in 96ms
npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree:init Completed in 9ms
npm timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 3ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm 23ms (cache hit)
npm timing idealTree:#root Completed in 72ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/npm Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 78ms
npm timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree Completed in 100ms
npm timing reify:loadTrees Completed in 429ms
npm timing reify:diffTrees Completed in 11ms
npm timing reify:retireShallow Completed in 18ms
npm timing reify:createSparse Completed in 1ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/npm Completed in 8838ms
npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
npm timing reify:diffTrees Completed in 16ms
npm timing reify:loadBundles Completed in 10431ms
npm timing reify:unpack Completed in 11ms
npm timing reify:unretire Completed in 74ms
npm timing build:queue Completed in 16ms
npm timing build:link:node_modules/npm/node_modules/opener Completed in 48ms
npm timing build:link:node_modules/npm Completed in 100ms
npm timing build:link:node_modules/npm/node_modules/qrcode-terminal Completed in 123ms
npm timing build:link Completed in 131ms
npm timing build:deps Completed in 153ms
npm timing build Completed in 157ms
npm timing reify:build Completed in 160ms
npm http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 806ms
npm timing auditReport:getReport Completed in 823ms
npm timing metavuln:cache:get:security-advisory:ansi-regex:gipfqiXURkkimm8+IyoEer5YC1ntqyorXe7xXSHfbxT4Q2N0cl4sjpCXLBfNQSZpCf2C6BCCpq61JXzBTOWL+g== Completed in 126ms
npm timing reify:trash Completed in 620ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-regex 143ms (cache hit)
npm timing metavuln:packument:ansi-regex Completed in 146ms
npm timing metavuln:load:security-advisory:ansi-regex:1004946 Completed in 1ms
npm timing metavuln:calculate:security-advisory:ansi-regex:1004946 Completed in 150ms
npm timing metavuln:cache:get:security-advisory:strip-ansi:VNH7BZLDPXeb+XyBHjziFezTzkb3wUEeYZF30Shwpq+9ErFf3ja9WpDN5+1N0ZmzJRrF78Jsd1Rv6URhv1/2cQ== Completed in 4ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi 13ms (cache hit)
npm timing metavuln:packument:strip-ansi Completed in 15ms
npm timing metavuln:load:security-advisory:strip-ansi:gipfqiXURkkimm8+IyoEer5YC1ntqyorXe7xXSHfbxT4Q2N0cl4sjpCXLBfNQSZpCf2C6BCCpq61JXzBTOWL+g== Completed in 0ms
npm timing metavuln:calculate:security-advisory:strip-ansi:gipfqiXURkkimm8+IyoEer5YC1ntqyorXe7xXSHfbxT4Q2N0cl4sjpCXLBfNQSZpCf2C6BCCpq61JXzBTOWL+g== Completed in 17ms
npm timing auditReport:init Completed in 171ms
npm timing reify:audit Completed in 1000ms
npm timing reify Completed in 11907ms

removed 176 packages, changed 3 packages, and audited 39 packages in 16s

1 moderate severity vulnerability

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.
npm timing command:install Completed in 12093ms
npm verb exit 0
npm timing npm Completed in 15691ms
npm info ok
```

Comment: have you tried `npm up`?

Comment: The output you seek simply isn't there. Silly or not, why not just run `npm info` before and after and see what's in there? Or maybe even check `package.json` yourself?

Comment: @kevintechie update returns very similar output to install

Comment: @AlexWayne ofc I can verify it myself but why do I need to do that when It clearly should know what it had done

Comment: Because the output of `npm install` isn't really intended to be processed as by a machine as a log of what was changed. It's intended to let a developer know that their dependencies are all present and accounted for, or they aren't. Sadly, I don't think there's an answer here that will satisfy you.

Comment: `npm install` doesn't care if anything was there previously so it doesn't keep track. You'll have to use something that does report like npm up or npm outdated. You could also use npm-check-updates, but you'll still need to npm i after.